# How to eliminate a row with a "file directory" for a parameter of hour

Tags: excel, vba

I have rows in excel with a file structure for example.

```
Row 1 c:\User\Folder100\13-25\File100.log
Row 2 c:\User\Folder200\11-16\File200.log
Row 3 c:\User\Folder300\21-20\File300.log
Row 4 c:\User\Folder400\13-25\File400.log
Row 5 c:\User\Folder400\9-10\File400.log
Row 6 c:\User\Folder500\8-16\File500.log
Row 7 c:\User\Folder600\8-16\File600.log
Row 8 c:\User\Folder700\11-16\File700.log
Row 9 c:\User\Folder700\9-40\File700.log
```

With the first rows there aren't any problem because the file logs are different but with the rows (4 and 5) a There are the same log in two different folders "c:\User\Folder400\13-25\" and c:\User\Folder400\9-10\ I would like to keep just 13-25(eliminate Row 5) because has more recent time.

Also with the lines 8 and 9 I just want to keep row 8 (11-16)

```
Row 1 c:\User\Folder100\13-25\File100.log
Row 2 c:\User\Folder200\11-16\File200.log
Row 3 c:\User\Folder300\21-20\File300.log
Row 4 c:\User\Folder400\13-25\File400.log
Row 6 c:\User\Folder500\8-16\File500.log
Row 7 c:\User\Folder600\8-16\File600.log
Row 8 c:\User\Folder700\11-16\File700.log
```

(eliminated row 5 and 9)

Do you know any Idea how to made it in VBA¿?

Comment: Will the repetitions always occur together?

Comment: the pattern by which those rows occure / by which you want to have them eliminated, is not clear. So the best advice i can give you, is to just delete this row - in VBA `Range("5:5").Delete`

Comment: Yes always together but can be another lines after this repetitions

Comment: @Jook but the problem is all the time the rows change

Comment: i know, but how can I help you with that, if you don't show HOW they are changing, or what the pattern is, to determine, which rows to keep and which to delete?!

Comment: do you mean if the first sub-folder (ie `Folder400`) and filename (`File400.log`) **both** match then that row should be deleted?

Comment: Yes Sorry if I havent be so clear with What I need For example Folder400 has tow SubFolders Folder400/13-25 and Folder400/9-10 I have to elimated the row with 9-10 because is older

Comment: How do you tell it is older? Because it contains `9-10` instead of `13-25`? Higher number in the folder name equals newer contents?

Comment: is it possible that two subfoldertimes overlap? like Folder400/10-12 and Folder400/11-13 or even Folder400/10-14?

Comment: mmm... The estructure XX-YY means XX hours and YY means minutes and not is not posible overlap folder the system create the folders one by one  and When I have a folder with two subfolder I have to keep withc folder has the highest hour and case are equas the folder with highest minutes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does **not exactly** serve the purpose, but serves **to illustrate a way** by which you could go about problems like this.

It takes into account the filename and the time string preceding it only. The folder can be added if necessary.

**Main Module:**

```
Option Explicit
Private dict As dictionary

'Prints the rows you need (time criterion applied) 
Private Sub FindDuplicates()
    Dim lastRow As Long, row As Long
    Dim x As Variant, v As Variant
    Dim fileName As String, timeString As String

    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    'Determine last row
    lastRow = Worksheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row

  'Iterate and store in dictionary  
  For row = 1 To lastRow
        x = Split(Cells(row, 1), Application.PathSeparator)
        fileName = x(UBound(x))
        timeString = x(UBound(x) - 1)
        AddDictEntry fileName, row, timeString
    Next row

    'Print results
    For Each v In dict.Keys
        Debug.Print "FileName: " & v & ", Recent Version: " & dict.Item(v)
    Next
End Sub
```

**To add/remove dictionary entries:**

```
Private Sub AddDictEntry(fileName As String, rowNo As Long, timeString As String)
    Dim timeParts As Variant, timeLong As Long

   'converts time string to long, for comparison
    timeParts = Split(timeString, "-")
    timeLong = CInt(timeParts(0)) * 100 + CInt(timeParts(1))

    'Adds entry to dictionary if time is more recent
    If (dict.Exists(fileName)) Then
        If CInt(dict.Item(fileName)) < timeLong Then
            dict(fileName) = timeLong
        End If
    Else
        dict.Add fileName, timeLong
    End If

End Sub
```

---

**Input:**

```
c:\User\Folder100\13-25\File100.log
c:\User\Folder200\11-16\File200.log
c:\User\Folder300\21-20\File300.log
c:\User\Folder400\13-25\File400.log
c:\User\Folder400\9-10\File400.log
c:\User\Folder300\22-20\File300.log
```

**Output:**

```
FileName: File100.log, Recent Version: 1325
FileName: File200.log, Recent Version: 1116
FileName: File300.log, Recent Version: 2220
FileName: File400.log, Recent Version: 1325
```

Comment: HEllo @Cthulhu I have a problem with Private dict As dictionary I never used before but I can Understand its a kind of array, but VBA return an error by not define. 
And you multiply by 100 for give more importance the hours but with for 100?, 
Can You help me to fix about the vba compilation problem but in general looks like What I need! thanks HEllo Cthulhu I have a problem with Private dict As dictionary I never used before but I can Understand its a kind of array, but VBA return an error by not define.

Comment: @JonathanRaulTapiaLopez You need to add a reference to `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` from the `Tools > References` menu. Once that is done, the above should run.

Comment: This would be a lot more helpful if you tied the dictionary back to rows - as it stands there is no connection to delete the required rows.

Comment: @brettdj I was thinking of a custom object which took 3 entries, to include row-number as well. Dictionary limits me to `key => value`. So I will have to append row number to the time, which seems quite bad.

Comment: @Cthulhu Yes :) I started the same way but put this method to one side when I realised the Dictionary was a variable short.

Comment: @brettdj I changed the time stored in the dictionary to Double and added `rowNo/100` to it. The solution feels dirty :D

Comment: Hey but If I add  Microsoft Scripting Runtime from the Tools > References Is going to work in another PC, or they have to do the same?

Comment: Hey I just checked I dont need to add the library in another PC :D

Comment: Hey It run the code and its what i need I have to modified and understand how dictionary works but thanks! @Cthulhu

Comment: Thanks man I modified the code to add an array into the dictionary because I have to have the hour and the path and thanks again now I know how dictionary works.

Answer (score 3):

The code below

1. uses a `RegEx` to extract the folder name and file number into two new columns (see pic below)
2. sorts the columns by column B and then by column C descending
3. delete the entire row where duplicate exists in column B using Excels `Remove Duplicates` functionality (the latest time comes first in column CV so it is preserved)
4. Removes the two working columns

*Update: The code below assumes that **both** the 1st folder after "User" **and** the file name much match for it to be a duplicate - the initial guidelines are still ambigious. This code does solve the example shown in the question*

[image]

```
Sub Sliced()
    Dim lngRow As Long
    Dim lngCalc As Long
    Dim objReg As Object
    Dim objDic As Object
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim X()
    Dim Y()

    Set rng1 = Range([a1], Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))

    'See Patrick Matthews excellent article on using Regular Expressions with VBA
    Set objReg = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    objReg.Pattern = "(.+\\){2}(.+\\)(\d+)\-\d+\\(.+)"

    'Speed up the code by turning off screenupdating and setting calculation to manual
    'Disable any code events that may occur when writing to cells
    With Application
        lngCalc = .Calculation
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    'Test each area in the user selected range
    X = rng1.Value2
    Y = X
    For lngRow = 1 To UBound(X)
        'replace the leading zeroes
        X(lngRow, 1) = objReg.Replace(X(lngRow, 1), "$2$4")
        Y(lngRow, 1) = objReg.Replace(Y(lngRow, 1), "$3")
    Next

    Columns("B:C").Insert
    rng1.Offset(0, 1) = X
    rng1.Offset(0, 2) = Y

    With ActiveSheet.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add Key:=rng1.Offset(0, 1), _
                        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .SortFields.Add Key:=rng1.Offset(0, 2), _
                        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .SetRange rng1.Cells(1).Offset(0, 1).Resize(rng1.Rows.Count, 2)
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=2, Header:=xlNo
    Columns("B:C").Delete

    'cleanup the Application settings
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .Calculation = lngCalc
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With

    Set objReg = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: whao there are to many lines I dont understand; Can be work for tree folders? or just for two?

Comment: I was checking the code but the problem is the directory can  change the only is starndar is the log and the folder contains that. but there are some parts of the code Im going to keep it

Comment: @JonathanRaulTapiaLopez in that case replace `X(lngRow, 1) = objReg.Replace(X(lngRow, 1), "$2$4")` with `X(lngRow, 1) = objReg.Replace(X(lngRow, 1), "$4")`